# Apply git stash pop to new submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-stash

I worked on two tasks at the same time : writing some code and make a folder of my working tree a submodule. When I switched task, I simply `git stash save` my modified files. The problem is that my modified files are now part of the new submodule.

And when I try to do a `git stash pop` on the top folder, I got a lot of conflicts

```
$ git stash pop
error: refusing to lose untracked file at 'folder/file1'
error: refusing to lose untracked file at 'folder/file2'
[and so on]

CONFLICT (modify/delete): [folder]/file1 deleted in Updated upstream and modified in Stashed changes. Version Stashed changes of [folder]/file1 left in tree. 
CONFLICT (modify/delete): [folder]/file2 deleted in Updated upstream and modified in Stashed changes. Version Stashed changes of [folder]/file2 left in tree. 
[and so on]
CONFLICT (file/directory): There is a directory with name [folder] in Stashed changes. Adding [folder] as [folder]~Updated upstream
```

Where [folder] is the previous folder/new submodule

I did a clean clone of the complete repo and the there is no problem with the new submodule.

Is there a way to transfer the stash to the submodule? Or to get the files in the stash and merge them manually in the submodule?

Comment: Git is such a pain sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a 'hacky' solution.

First I made a git patch from my stash with `git stash show stash@{0} -p`.

Then I manually edited the patch to modify my paths and the remove the unwanted things.

Then `git patch mypatch.patch` to apply the changes to my submodule. It worked on first try and seems to build without any trouble.